# Plotting a function of Theta and Phi as a color plot on a sphere

Tags: matlab, surface

I am trying to prepare this exercise in my class on Matlab (as a part of Applied Physics lab for CS engineers) where you have to model the temperature fluctuation over the surface a planet whose one side always faces the parent star and one side is  always away from it (half frozen-half baked). Here is the function I am using:

T(Theta, Phi) = T0 + T1*sin^2(Theta) + T2*(1+sin(Phi))

I want to plot the above function on a surface of a sphere as a color plot i.e. the color of a point on the surface should represent the temperature T at the point. How can I go about doing it?

All I have done so far gives me a plot like this:
[image]

I want something like the image below but with different color distribution of course, given according to the function I gave above.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `"I want to plot the above function on a surface of a sphere"`? A sphere is a sphere.  Are you saying that you want to map the colours onto a sphere? Or do you want to create a closed 3D object with the above shape, i.e just make the edges on the respective side to meet so to speak?

Comment: Meaning, the color on the surface of the sphere at a point should represent value of temperature at that point, (Theta, Phi).

Comment: Something like this, http://i.stack.imgur.com/HQXDC.png. With different color distribution of course, given according to the function I gave in the question.

Comment: http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8585-3d-plot-on-a-spherical-surface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it partially:

```
T0 = 2 ; T1 = 30  ; T2 = 120 ; %// set your boundary conditions here

[X,Y,Z] = sphere(50) ; %// generate coordinates of a sphere
hs = surf(X,Y,Z)     ; %// display the sphere and retrieve the handle to the graphic object
axis equal           ; %// set the axis ratio so the sphere appear as a sphere
shading interp       ; %// small refinement to not see the grid, you can comment that

[azimuth,elevation,r] = cart2sph(X,Y,Z) ;               %// Convert cartesian coordinates to spherical referential
T = T0 + T1*sin(azimuth).^2 + T2.*(1+sin(elevation)) ;  %// Calculate the temperature according to your model
set(hs,'CData',T) ;                                     %// update the sphere graphic object with the new temperature as a collor coding
```

[image: the sphere]

Now you still have to adjust your initial conditions `T0`, `T1` and `T3`, and may be also add some rotations in case your "hot" and "cold" points are not at the poles.

Comment: You can also do surf(X, Y, Z, T) once you have created T.

Comment: @nivag, yes indeed. We could even reduce the number of line further, but seeing how the OP had trouble plotting a spherical shape, I opted to separate the _sphere plotting_ and the _temperature data application_ operations.

Comment: Thanks Hoki! It looks exactly like I wanted it!